# MongoDB Update Item in Array inside Array

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, backend

I want to update an existing item inside of an array in an array.

The structure of my document looks like the following:

```
    {
  "_id":"a1",
  "projects":[{
    "_id": "b1",
    "title":"Title A",
    "task":[
           {"_id": "c1",
            "title":"Title B"},
            {"_id": "c2",
            "title":"Title C"},
            {"_id": "c3",
            "title":"Title D"}
          ],

}]
}
```

Let's say we want to change the "task" :

```
{"_id": "c2",
 "title":"Title C"}
```

to

```
{"_id": "c2",
 "title":"Title C1"}
```

Does someone know a proper way to update this subdocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a combination of `$set` with the [posititonal operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) and `arrayFilters`, this should be doable:

```
db.getCollection('so-test').updateOne(
   { _id: "a1"},
   { $set: { "projects.$[].task.$[task].title": "Title C1" } },
   { arrayFilters: [  {"task.title": "Title C"} ]}
)
```